# Capture ctrl keydown event in iOS (mobile safari)

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile-safari

I'm trying to detect when a user is pressing ctrl key in safari on iOS (9.3).
But the keydown event is never triggered.

Note: **I'm using an external bluetooth Mac keyboard**

http://jsfiddle.net/ms25mneL/1/

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```

I have noticed that the event does trigger on safari on Mac OS X but not on iOS. Is there another way to detect this on iOS (9.3)?

Comment: Sorry I updated the question. I forgot to mention i'm using an external bluetooth keyboard

Comment: Also have a look at the question above and try to use a different event.

Comment: That is not the problem, the event triggers for all other keys. (except shift, alt and meta keys,...)  Also I tried binding on other events but it doesn't help.